# Show that $\int \frac{ 2f(x)}{(e^{3x} -2)^3}~dx $=$\frac{2(1-e^{3x})}{3(e^{3x} -2)^2}+c~$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I Show that $$\int \frac{ 2f(x)}{(e^{3x} -2)^3}\,\mathrm{d}x =\frac{2(1-e^{3x})}{3(e^{3x} -2)^2}+c$$

I get the $f(x)=\dfrac{e^{3x} -2)^3}{(e^x-2e^{-2x})^3}$ then I am stuck what should I do.please I need to see the working because I wanted to understand it.
The previous question is asking  to determine function of f(x) by giving equation $\frac{2}{(e^x -2e^(-2x))^3}$=$\frac{2f(x)}{(e^(3x)-2)^3}$.  I calculate the f(x) and please correct me if i am wrong because i am new to this chapter.
The exponent power is actually 3x i am sorry because i do not know how to do that

Comment: I am sorry the exponent power is 3x actually

Comment: i have got $$e^{6x}=f(x)$$

Comment: Can you show how you got it

Comment: I think that the question must be if $\int \frac{ 2f(x)}{(e^{3x} -2)^3}~dx $=$\frac{2(1-e^{3x})}{3(e^{3x} -2)^2}+c~$ then find $f(x)$

Comment: No angelo i already listed the question about f(x)

Answer (score 1):

differentiating the right side we get 
$$-2\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{3\,x}}}{ \left( {{\rm e}^{3\,x}}-2 \right) ^{2}}
}-4\,{\frac { \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{3\,x}} \right) {{\rm e}^{3\,x}}}{
 \left( {{\rm e}^{3\,x}}-2 \right) ^{3}}}$$                              multiplying by $$(e^{3x}-2)^3$$
and simplifying we obtain $$e^{6x}$$

Comment: So aFter that how should i proceed